# How can i separate a string that is in a list into 2 parts?

Tags: python, string, list

I currently have a list that looks like the following:

```
list = ['325 153\n', '509 387\n', '419 397\n']
```

I am wondering how could i access these strings individually so i could use it in a function such as

```
for (x, y) in list:
```

where x is the first number of the string and y is the second number (separated by the space)

Is a good way to do this to turn the string into tuples somehow? I have tried using the 'split' function as i believe it is not valid for a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a_list = ['325 153\n', '509 387\n', '419 397\n']
>>> [ i.split() for i in a_list ]
[['325', '153'], ['509', '387'], ['419', '397']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate one the elements of the list:

```
for elem in list:
    a, b = elem.split()[0], elem.split()[1]
```

a and b will be the elements and you can process them just as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [tuple(x.split()) for x in list]
```

this will return you a list of tuples

Answer (score 1):

There is the `split()` method for string. Before using it you should use `strip()` to get rid of the training `\n`. At the end you can put both into a list comprehension:

```
for x, y in [item.strip().split(" ", 1) for item in lst]:
```

Note that I replace `list` with `lst`. `list` is a built-in type and should not be used as variable name.